# Geometric v. arithmetic mean

Tags: mean, geometric-distribution, geometric-mean

According to [this extract of a paper](http://jarrodwilcox.com/expert-investor/diversification-helps-growth/) posted on the web, the average return of a fair coin flip that pays 100% for heads and loses 50 percent for tails over 3 periods is 25 percent per period, while the geometric mean or compound annual return is 8.3 percent.

To calculate the average return, you first calculate the terminal value then calculate the equivalent per period value. The terminal values is $0.125\cdot 8 + 0.375\cdot 2 + 0.375\cdot 0.5 + 0.125\cdot 0.125$, or $1.9531$ and the per period value is  $1.9531^{1/3}$, or $1.25$. Subtracting $1$ gets you $25\%$ per period.

To calculate the average geometric return or or mean compound return you take the cube root of each possible outcome and then apply the probabilities to each of the results.  So the geometric mean is $0.125\cdot 100\% + 0.375\cdot 26\% + 0.375\cdot (-20.6\%) + 0.125\cdot (-50\%)$, or only $8.3\%$.

My question is how should one interpret the geometric mean return?  Does it describe the expected growth in your capital such that if I ran an experiment where I made a number of 3 year investments, the expected growth of my capital over the 3 years would be $8.3\%$?

Why does the the geometric mean return decline with with period?

Comment: One thing missing from this question is the duration of a "period." This is crucial because you are attempting to translate a per-period return to an annual mean return.

Comment: The duration of a period is 1 year. So the average return is 25% per year for 3 years and the 8.3% geometric mean is the geometric average return per year for 3 years